# Common-Emitter Analysis

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt, common-emitter

[image]

I am making an error in the analysis of the above circuit.
$$i_i=i_b \implies v_1=i_b\cdot r_{\pi}$$
So the value of $$g_m v_1 = g_m\cdot r_{\pi}i _b= \beta i_b$$

But, this is the same current (\$i_c = \beta i_b \$) flowing through the collector branch (i.e through \$ R_C\$) which means the current through \$ r_O\$ is identically zero which is a contradiction.

Where did I go wrong?

Edit: On further inspection, it seems my question is akin to asking whether $$i_c=\beta i_b$$ is valid when we include the Early effect (responsible for \$ r_o \$). Can anybody confirm this?

Edit2: I think I was not able to express my question properly...So here is a hand-drawn figure
[image]

Have I marked \$i_c\$ properly? And if yes, since it is equal to \$g_mv_1\$ using KCL at the output voltage node , there is no current through \$r_o\$. How so?

Comment: What are you asking about? In your circuit, we have \$I_C = I_{RC} + I_{r_o} = \$ Also notice that $$gm*V_i =I_{RC} + I_{r_o} $$ and $$V_O = - I_C*R_C||r_o  = - gm V_I R_C||r_o $$

Comment: @G36 but I showed above \$ g_m*v_i = \beta i_b = i_c = i_{R_{C}}  \$ which means \$ i_{r_0}\$ is zero. Where am I wrong in this part?

Comment: Simply do the KCL   \$\beta i_b = i_{Rc} + i_{ro}\$

Comment: @G36 I understand that but I showed separately that \$ i_c = i_{R_c} = \beta i_b \$

Comment: But this is only true if \$r_o >> R_C\$

Comment: @G36 Why though? Is my derivation in my post wrong somewhere? Of course it is, but can you point out the step where I go wrong (I mean \$ i_c \$ being the collector current flows through the resistor \$ R_C\$ only right)

Comment: You violate Kirchhoff's First Law.

Comment: @G36 Umm...in which step can you indicate?

Comment: By assuming that \$\beta i_b = i_{Rc}\$  This is wrong.

Comment: @G36 I get it now...I thought earlier \$i_c\$(being the collector current) would only flow through the collector branch consisting of \$R_C\$ and hence equal \$i_{R_C}\$(since the DC version \$I_C\$ flows through that) but I understand now that is not correct..Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is no contradiction - however, you must not forget, that the equivalent small-signal diagram is not for the BJT alone but for the whole amplifier circuit.

That means:

It is correct that the current through the collector node is ic=beta*ib - however, in your equivalent diagram the output is the signal voltage vo (and not ic). Therefore, the internal source resistance (ro) must be taken into accout. This leads to a small reduction in vo - and in the small-signal diagram both resistors are in parallel (Rc||ro).

Remember: Each non-ideal source contains a source resistance: An ideal voltage source has a series resistance and an ideal current source has a parallel resistance (in our case ro).

Comment: What confuses me is that if indeed \$ i_c \$ flows completely through \$R_c \$,then no current flows through the internal output resistance, right? How can that be true?

Comment: In my answer I have tried to explain the difference - perhaps not clear enough?

Comment: Just one small doubt, what is the current through \$ r_o \$?

Comment: You can compute this current through ro using the current divider rule: I_ro=gmv1*Rc(Rc+ro)

Comment: Yes, I get that...I think, my confusion is what is meant by \$i_c\$ in the circuit. I believe it is solely the current through the collector resistor and as in my calculations above, \$g_mv_1\$ also turned out be equal to collector current (\$i_c\$) so how can there be any current  in \$r_o\$ or does the definition of collector current in this small signal case encompass both \$R_c\$ and \$r_o\$...Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Dont confuse Ic with ic. The latter is just the signal current - the variations in Ic caused by a variation in Vin. In the circuit diagram with the transistor symbol you cannot see the current source - only the equivalent linearized small-signal diagram can show if the current source is ideal or lossy. In principle, such considerations apply to all circuit elements. Also the resistor symbol does not reflect the case that for high frequencies there are capacitive and inductive parasitics.

Comment: Sorry if this is repetitive (I get your point about the lossy current source), but can you describe the branches through which \$i_c\$ is flowing and if it is equal to \$g_mv_1\$

Comment: Let me try it in words: The current Ic (not ic) is the current out of the collector node and goes through Rc. Question: When Ic is varying (due to a varying  Vin) will this variation ic completely (!) transferred to  a corresponding voltage ic*Rc ? Answer: No. A negative voltage change at the collector [-d(Vce)] caused by a positive input voltage will cause a small decrease in Ic (Early effect). Hence, the full current swing will not be transferred into a corresponding voltage output swing icRc. In the equivalent diagram, this fact is modelled with a large parallel (dynamic) resistance ro.

Comment: Oh. That is quite a good explanation of the working of the circuit. Can you check my recent uploaded diagram of the equivalent small-signal circuit and verify if I have marked \$i_c = \beta i_b \$ correctly?

Comment: No - not correct. The current (beta * ib)=(gm * v1) is the current into the collector node. This current consists of two parts (through ro resp. Rc)

Comment: Okay, that is what I wanted confirmation on. Thanks a lot for sticking with me..just one last confirmation, that implies current through \$ R_c \$ can be found by dividing \$i_c=g_mv_1=\beta i_b\$ between \$r_o\$ and \$R_c\$ using the current divider rule and hence wouldn't equal \$i_c\$ as stated in your answer. I think you can change that and I would accept the answer.... Again, Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for the hint - I followed your recommendation.